# Why I did not get any error? between these lines--- typedef int floa[1]; floa a[5]={5,6,1,2,6,8};

Tags: c

please explain the logic behind the code/..

I do in codeblock. i got answer 20. why? please explain.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
    typedef int floa[1];
    floa a[5]={5,6,1,2,6,8};

    printf("the value is %u",sizeof(a));
    return 0;
}
```

I should get an error but I did not why?

Comment: "I should get an error but I did not why?" Why?

Comment: MSVC gives `error C2078: too many initializers`.

Comment: It's not a good idea to hide array and pointer types inside typedefs for this very reason: it makes the code hard to read and reason about.

Comment: A `typedef` on an *array of one, which is not really an array* is super odd.

Comment: This is weird code. Is it really defining an array of 5 arrays of 1 int? Is that even legal? The size of that should indeed be 20, if the structure is at all valid!

Answer (score 1):

### crux is here:  typedef int floa[1]

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                      
int main()                                                                                              
{                                                                                                           
    typedef int floa[3];                                                                                
    floa a[4]={5,6,1,2};                                                                                

    printf("the value is %u value:%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d",sizeof(a), a[0][0], a[0][1], a[0][2], a[0][3], a[1][0], a[1][1], a[1][2], a[1][3]);
    return 0;                                                                                           
}
```

Run above code and you will understand ur code. above code gives size = 48, so basically your typedef is creating "m x n" matrix effect.

But as Lee Daniel Crocker mentioned, it is not good idea to hide the array within typedef.